# search set of strings using cscope

Tags: linux, string, search, cscope

I have cscope working fine on my project containing multiple files. In eclipse and other IDEs, there is provision for searching a string for example "how are you" in the whole project. Does cscope has the support for this feature ? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

After the cscope browser has been opened, type **'?'** to see the help page. It displays a list of operations that you can perform :

```
Find this C symbol:
Find this global definition:
Find functions called by this function:
Find functions calling this function:
Find this text string:
Change this text string:
Find this egrep pattern:
Find this file:
Find files #including this file:
```

Select the type of search that you'd like to perform, type in your search term and hit Enter.

At the top of the screen Cscope will display a list of results with the file, function, and line where the search term was found.